# Comparing cardinalities of the spectrum of two masas in $B(H)$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, ultrafilters, boolean-algebras, stone-cech-compactification

If I imagine that (the self-adjoint part of) a C*-algebra $A$ represents the algebra of observables of some quantum system, then [certain](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2177) [perspectives](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00220-009-0865-6) on algebraic quantum theory would ask me to imagine that each (maximal) commutative C*-subalgebra $C \subseteq A$ provides a (maximal) "classical snapshot" of this quantum system.  Gelfand duality yields that $C \cong C(X)$ for the compact Hausdorff space $X = \mathrm{Spec}(C)$, so I would picture $X$ as a classical state space that (maximally) "approximates" the would-be quantum state space corresponding to $A$.

I would like to know how different these spaces $X$ can be as the maximal commutative $*$-subalgebra $C \subseteq A$ varies.  Specifically, can it happen that these have different cardinalities?

I'm interested in the particular case $A = B(H)$ for a separable Hilbert space $H$ and two of its well-known masas: the continuous one $C \cong L^\infty[0,1] \subseteq A$ and discrete one $D \cong \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq A$.  Thus I ask:

> **Q:** Is there a bijection between the Gelfand spectra $\mathrm{Spec}(C)$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(D)$ for the continuous and discrete masas $C,D \subseteq B(H)$?

It's possible to describe these spectra in more explicit terms using Boolean algebra.  Note that each of these masas is an (A)W*-algebra.  By a combination of Gelfand and Stone dualities (see [section 2 of this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5778) for a bit more detail), the spectrum of a commutative AW*-algebra $K$ is the [Stone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) of the complete Boolean algebra $\mathrm{Proj}(K)$ of projections in $K$, whose points are the ultrafilters of $\mathrm{Proj}(K)$.

The continuous masa $C \cong L^\infty[0,1]$ has $\mathrm{Proj}(C)$ isomorphic to the Boolean algebra of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ modulo the null sets.  I have just learned through the magic of Wikipedia that this is called the [random algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_algebra); I will denote it by $B$.

The discrete masa $D \cong \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ has $\mathrm{Proj}(D)$ isomorphic to the power set Boolean algebra $2^\mathbb{N}$.  (Note that an ultrafilter on the Boolean algebra $2^\mathbb{N}$ is alternatively referred to as an ultrafilter on the set $\mathbb{N}$.)

Thus my question is equivalent to:

> **Q':** Is there a bijection between the sets of ultrafilters on the random algebra $B$ and the power set algebra $2^\mathbb{N}$?

I am aware that $\mathrm{Spec}(D)$ has spectrum homeomorphic to the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\mathbb{N}$ of the discrete space $\mathbb{N}$, and that this space has various properties that depend on set-theoretic assumptions.  Now that I know what the random algebra is called, I see that it bears a relationship to forcing.  Thus I can imagine that the answer to my question could be independent of ZFC.  Nevertheless, as I am not asking exactly what the cardinality of this spectrum is, but whether it is in bijection with some other (possibly complicated) spectrum, I have an ounce of hope that this can indeed be decided in ZFC.

(By the way, the [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_von_Neumann_algebra#Classification) of the possible masas of $B(H)$ implies that, if the answer to my question is affirmative, then the spectra of all masas of $B(H)$ are in bijection with one another.)

Comment: I don't understand your last statement. Isomorphic in what category?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it does not really have anything to do with MASAs. YOu are merely comparing the Gelfand spectra of the two Banach algebras $L^\infty[0,1]$ and $\ell^\infty({\bf N})$ and asking if the two spectra have the same cardinality -- is that correct?

Comment: @YemonChoi, I meant in the category of sets.  I'll edit accordingly in a moment.  And you're right about my question; but the only reason that I would dream to ask if these spectra have the same cardinality is that they both occur as masas of the same C*-algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. The spectra of $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$ have the same cardinality, namely $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Indeed, every infinite, compact $F$-space space (in particular, an extremely disconnected compact space such as the spectrum of $L_\infty$) contains a copy of $\beta \mathbb{N}$ (which happens to be the spectrum of $\ell_\infty$). This is 14N(5) in

> L. Gillman and M. Jerison, *Rings of continuous functions*, van Nostrand Reinhold, New York, 1960.

and it is quite elementary. The [Hausdorff–Pospíšil theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83526/the-set-of-ultrafilters-on-an-infinite-set) implies that $|\beta\mathbb{N}|=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. Thus,  $2^{\mathfrak{c}}\leqslant |{\rm spec}\, L_\infty|$.

I *claim* that the cardinality of ${\rm spec}\, L_\infty$ cannot be bigger than $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. Indeed, $L_\infty^*$ is a bidual of a separable Banach space, hence by [Goldstine's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem), it is separable in the weak*-topology. [Every separable space has cardinality at most $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space#Cardinality). Thus 
$|{\rm spec}\, L_\infty|\leqslant |L_\infty^*|\leqslant 2^{\mathfrak{c}}.$

Comment: Thank you!  This answer is so nice, especially the use of (pre)duals, that I now suspect a similar argument could be made for the spectrum of masas of $B(H)$, independent of the dimension of $H$.

Comment: @Manny Reyes, for non-separable spaces the situation is trickier but I guess that the only types of masas are the following: $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$ and $L_\infty(\{0,1\}^\lambda)$ and certain $\ell_\infty$-sums of them ($\lambda$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space) but at the end of the day the spectra will have the same cardinality.

Comment: I was thinking that one might be able to work even without resorting to an explicit description.  If $C \subseteq B(H)$ is a masa, then the predual $C_*$ will be a homomorphic image of $B(H)_*$ (trace class operators), giving upper bounds on $C_*$ and then presumably on $C^* = (C_*)^{**}$.  If this upper bound coincides with $|\mathrm{Spec}(\ell^\infty(\dim(H))| = 2^{2^{\dim(H)}}$, and if one can similarly embed $\beta \dim(H)$ into $\mathrm{Spec}(C)$, then we'd have effectively the same proof.

Comment: No, in general you cannot embed $\beta \lambda$ into ${\rm spec}\, L_\infty(\{0,1\}^{\lambda})$. This fails for all uncountable $\lambda$. (You will find this in old papers of H. P. Rosenthal.)

Comment: OK, that's no good.  Can we get an injective $*$-homomorphism $\ell^\infty(\lambda) \hookrightarrow L^\infty([0,1]^\lambda)$, perhaps?  (We could construct a normal $*$-homomorphism if there are $\lambda$-many orthogonal projections in the latter algebra that sum to 1.)  This would give a surjection of spectra in the opposite direction.

Comment: No, if $K$ satisfies the countable chain condition (and certainly the spectrum $K$ of $L_\infty(\mu)$ for a probability measure $\mu$ does), then no subspace of $C(K)$ is isomorphic to $c_0(\omega_1)$. (This is easy modulo certain prehistoric facts from Banach space theory.)

I suggest deleting the old comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21474/discussion-between-manny-reyes-and-tomek-kania).